# .net 8 Razor Pages routing without default route to @page directive

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-routing

I have an .net 8 razor page application where i've added page routes from database with the following code:

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute(route.FullName, route.Key.ToString());
```

For example i've added the page route /A64592D0-05AD-4E0D-8A0C-5E5259800A19 for the page /Account/Login.
Now I want to avoid that someone can access the page directly with /Account/Login.

Background: Each page can be accessed by more then one route in our navigation tree, this way it's possible to evaluate on which position the user is currently on the tree and handle different permissions based on the position and user.

I just could set the @page directive to some unused value, but that wouldn't avoid the possibility to access the page with that value.

How can i remove or disable the default page route for all pages?

Comment: Security by obfuscation is not security

Comment: Has nothing to to with obfuscation. I also could give my custom routes normal names, the only thing i don't want is the default route to be accessible because i can't guarantee that the @page directive will always be in sync with the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [PageRouteModelConvention](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/custom-route-conventions) to clear all the default routes. An example would look like this:

```
public class CustomPageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        model.Selectors.Clear();
    }
}
```

Then you register it in *Program.cs*, ensuring you make your `AddPageRoute` calls afterwards:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new CustomPageRouteModelConvention());
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Account/Login", "A64592D0-05AD-4E0D-8A0C-5E5259800A19");
});
```

Or depending on your logic, you could add the custom routes within the custom `PageRouteModelConvention`. The `Apply` method is called for every page in your app once at startup.